# Autostart and CurrentDirectory

Tags: windows, winapi

I am very confused about the WindowsAPI function

> GetCurrentDirectory

When my application get's started from the autostart (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) the current directory is ALWAYS : %windir%\system32

Why is that?

Comment: What would you expect it to be? Did you set it to be somewhere else?

Comment: I'm just curious why windows sets the currentdirectory to system32

Comment: That's as expected.  By default, applications inherit the current directory from the parent process, and most system components use system32 as the current directory.  What were you expecting?  Why does it matter?

Comment: Because that was the current directory of the part of Windows that processes the AutoStart key, and you haven't told it to be anywhere else. If you expect a certain directory, use full pathnames (which you can get at runtime in your own process).

Comment: I know how to get the full path. But when I double click an application and start it , explorer.exe is the parent process. When it's autostarted the parent process is also explorer.exe which is located in Windows.

Comment: No, not quite. When you double-click it in Explorer, the current directory is the location of the file you're double-clicking to launch (you set it by going there with Explorer before double-clicking, remember?), and that's set when the app is started (unless you say otherwise in a shortcut, in which case the working directory from the shortcut is used to set the current directory of the app).

Comment: @HarryJohnston: You got there first. You should post an answer with what you commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's as expected. By default, applications inherit the current directory from the parent process, and most system components use system32 as the current directory.

When you launch an application by double-clicking, Explorer goes to the trouble of explicitly setting the current directory.  When an application is launched from the Run key, it doesn't.  There's probably no particular reason why not, just that the programmers who wrote the code for processing the Run key either didn't think about it or didn't think it was worth the effort.