# C auto start program on windows can't use files

Tags: c, windows

I create a program to auto start with Windows, using registry:

```
CURRENT_USER\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

when Windows starts, the program starts too, the problem is that on auto start he can't manipulate files, when I open the program he can do everything.

Using `GetLastError` I can see the error code is 5: access denied, strerror return "access denied" and using FormatString the message is something like: "Error description 5: Access denied.

Can someone explain why is this hapening?

Comment: How are you opening these files? Please show the actual code. The default current directory for autostart is [`%WINDIR%\System32`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965531/autostart-and-currentdirectory). I'm guessing, but I'd say you are trying to open files for write in the current directory and you are not allowed to write to the system directory.

Comment: I'd guess that the current working directories are different. Try printing the working directory before opening the files.

Comment: Which file are you opening ?

Answer (score 1):

The program was starting from System32, so to create the files in the exe dir, is better use `GetModuleFileName`.

Comment: Writing files in the directory of the executable is bad practice.

Comment: maybe in the current user AppData directory

Comment: Indeed, a program should write its permanent files (settings, documents) into the user's AppData directory, in a subdirectory (AppData\<your_company>\<your_program>). Use function [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the actual path of user's AppData. Temporary files can be created in the temp directory (function [`GetTempPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) knows where it is).